# pyqtgraph: how to prevent viewbox from stretching with view?

Tags: python, qt, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to create a list of plots one below the other, on the same axes.
I want to be able to scroll through the plots, and when resizing the view I want to display more plots rather than enlarging the existing plots.

I subclasses `PlotWidget` and tried to manipulate `resizeEvent` and `sizePolicy` and nothing worked.

Any idea?

Thanks

#### Update:

This is the [initial view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XREvz.png). When changing the window's height I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKsHG.png).
What I'm trying to achieve is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4H4G.png).

Also, I would like to add a vertical scrollbar instead of vertical panning.

#### Update:

Apparently pyqtgraph isn't a good fit for what I'm trying to do. I ended up implementing with `QGraphicsScene` and `QGraphicsView`.

Comment: You probably want to embed the plot widget inside a [`QScrollArea`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html).

Comment: Thanks @bnaecker for the reply. The problem is that the axes would scroll too, wouldn't they?

Comment: IIUC, you want a subset of the plots visible. When you resize the window, more plots should become visible, but they should not change size. An analogy would be how the individual items on a webpage don't change size when you resize (or scroll), they just go in and out of view. If that's what you're looking for, a scroll area will do that for you.

Comment: That's almost what I mean - the plot items should become visible when resizing - but I want the grid and ticks to stay in place and resize with the window.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you have in mind. "Stay in place" and "resize with the window" seem mutually exclusive to me. If you can add as much detail about your desired behavior to the question (even a graphic!), that would really help. I might suggest looking at the QScrollArea documentation to see if that has the behavior you want, or if it points you to the widget which does.

Comment: @bnaecker updated the question with some graphics